# Access variables from parent scope in anonymous PHP function

Tags: php, closures

I want to write a function that does some dirty work logging a transaction, but the anonymous function scope does not seem to register the parent scope `$db` and `$value` variables. How can I pass the variables into the closure?

Ironically, the SO tag 'closures' does not describe the PHP version of it very accurately...?

```
class controller
{
    function submit()
    {
        $db = new database();
        $result = $db->execute_tx(function() {
            $db->insert_model_a($value_a); // ERROR: $db is non-object
            $db->insert_model_b($value_b);
        });
    }
}

class database
{
   function execute_tx($atomic_action)
   {
        try
        { 
            $this->start();
            $atomic_action();
            $this->commit();
            // etc..
        }
        catch(...)
        { 
            $this->rollback();
            // etc..
        } 
        finally
        {
            // etc..
        }
   }

   function insert_model_a() { ... }
   function insert_model_b() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use the `use` keyword to bind variables into the function's scope.

```
function() use ($db) {
```

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be declared in the function header [using `use`].
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: is this the ONLY way? Because I have like 10 to 15 values in some submit and I have many submits to go through...

Comment: Yes. You must explicitly import the variables that you want the closure to close over.

Comment: Don't forget that you can pass in variables through normal function arguments too.

Comment: @Jake If you have a state of 10-15 values in that function, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Jack Why is that so? Why so certain?

Comment: @Jake it's common practice to group multiple values, such as parameters, into an array.

Comment: @jack point taken. Since this is the only way, I have began modifying the variables into array and just use($arr) instead.

Comment: @Jack is that a good practice or something you are forced to do because of the way closures work in PHP?.

Comment: This just ended 45 minutes of frustration. Wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 8.0, [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) have been available. These inherit variables from the parent scope without any declarations:

> Arrow functions support the same features as [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), except that using variables from the parent scope is always automatic.

They are intended for use with single expressions, so are not ideal for the code in the question, but using two of them would work:

```php
class Controller
{
    function submit()
    {
        $db = new database();
        // one assumes $value_a and $value_b are defined in the submit method
        $result = $db->execute_tx(fn() => $db->insert_model_a($value_a));
        $result = $db->execute_tx(fn() => $db->insert_model_b($value_b));
    }
}
```