# Is there any way to pass variable in rememberForever callback?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have following code,

```
\Cache::rememberForever('Roles', function() {
    return RoleModel
        ::where('ParentRoleID' >= $CurrenctUserRoleID)
        ->get();
});
```

Issue is: I am getting Error

> Undefined variable: CurrenctUserRoleID

**Question**: Is there any way to pass variable in callback?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access variables from parent scope in anonymous PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042197/access-variables-from-parent-scope-in-anonymous-php-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Callback function using variables calculated outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588714/callback-function-using-variables-calculated-outside-of-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this (Notice the use of `use` keyword):

```php
$CurrenctUserRoleID = 1; // Some id

\Cache::rememberForever('Roles', function() use($CurrenctUserRoleID) {
    return RoleModel
    ::where('ParentRoleID' >= $CurrenctUserRoleID)
    ->get();
});
```

Check the `PHP` manual: [Inheriting variables from the parent scope](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 1):

[PHP.net - anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) - Example #3

You aren't passing anything with the callback as you are not the caller of that callback. You are telling PHP to use a variable from the parent scope.

```
function (...) use (...) { ... }
```