# Passing outer function parameter to inner function Laravel

Tags: laravel-8

I have the code bellow aimed at retrieving all the service providers using the service ID

```
  public function getProvidersByPackage($id = null){
    $package_id = $id;
        $providers = ServiceProvider::whereHas('services', function($query) {
            $query->where('packages.id', 1);
        })->get();
        dd($providers);
    }
```

I would like to replace the constant 1 with the variable $id passed to the outer function getProvidersByPackage()
my problem is that when I try the following

```
      public function getProvidersByPackage($id = null){
$package_id = $id;
    $providers = ServiceProvider::whereHas('services', function($query) {
        $query->where('packages.id', $id);
    })->get();
    dd($providers);
}
```

I get the error $id is not defined and when I try

```
     public function getProvidersByPackage($id = null){
    $package_id = $id;
        $providers = ServiceProvider::whereHas('services', function(&$package_id, $query) {
            $query->where('package.package_id', $package_id);
        })->get();
}
```

I get the ArgumentCountError bellow

```
    Too few arguments to function   
    App\Http\Controllers\ShopController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(), 1 passed in
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 1207 
    and exactly 2 expected
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In PHP, what is a closure and why does it use the "use" identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-what-is-a-closure-and-why-does-it-use-the-use-identifier)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042197/access-variables-from-parent-scope-in-anonymous-php-function

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692817/whats-the-difference-between-closure-parameters-and-the-use-keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, you can [pass a variable to a closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) using the `use` syntax

```
public function getProvidersByPackage($id = null) {
    $package_id = $id;
    $providers  = ServiceProvider::whereHas('services', function ($query) use ($package_id) {
                $query->where('package.package_id', $package_id);
            })->get();
}
```